# Is it safe for me to watch Shingeki! Kyojin Chuugakkou as an anime-only viewer?

Tags: attack-on-titan

I have only watched (season one of) the *Shingeki no Kyojin* anime, and have not read any of the manga.

As I watch the *Shingeki! Kyojin Chuugakkou* anime, which is airing this season, I am starting to get a sense that I am at risk of being spoiled for content which is currently manga-only. Nothing glaring comes to mind yet (though that could just be because e.g. I'm failing to notice gags that are based on manga-only content), though there's [a character from episode 8 who I don't think I know](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/27527/who-is-this-ghost-from-episode-8-of-shingeki-kyojin-chuugakkou), and an altercation between two characters in episode 3 that I was told comes from a flashback that hasn't been animated yet.

Can someone who has read the (main) manga and is watching *Shingeki! Kyojin Chuugakkou* (and perhaps has read the source manga for that) tell me how much of a risk I'm at of spoiling myself for content that hasn't been animated yet?

(If there's a high risk of spoilage, I figure I may as well put it off until season 2 airs in 2016.)

Comment: Having read the original manga, I think the worse case scenario is you not getting a few gags and not recognising a few characters, there has not been that much spoilers and references that would spoil the 2nd season for you since the characters are depicted in a silly fashion without relation to the main plot of the original manga.

Comment: Hahahaha 2016 remember when we were all so innocent?

Comment: @senshin Dude, that's exactly what I thought when I first watched that spin-off series XD I didn't expect them to do something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend watching the anime first as a good overview of the series. Then read the manga, to cover any: plot holes/extras/gags and to get more info. It doesn't really matter because the anime (**most** of the time) follows the manga (In Soul Eater, the anime and manga are different but the story continues differently so it isn't spoiling anything because it's a different story).